# SQL join for comparing this year vs last year sales by store and by product

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm trying to compare this year vs last sales by store and by product.

The idea behind my SQL is to create a base table for 24 months rolling data and perform a join on transaction date - 1 year. This is somewhat complicated that my data is aggregated by date, by store and by product.

My code is as below. And my issue is that when i do a left join, the numbers for this year and last year doesn't match up. For example, feb-19 last year sales should equal to feb-18 this year sales, but I am not getting this result.

My guess is that last year has certain stores and products that are not available this year but I have no idea how to resolve this. I tried a full join, but the numbers are also off. Appreciate any feedback please!

```
-- extract sales by day, store, product
select business_date, store_code, product_code, 
sum(sales) as sales
into #temp1
from sales_table
where business_date >= date_trunc('month', dateadd('month', -24, sysdate))
group by business_date, store_code, product_code;


-- compare this year against last year
select ty.*, ly.sales as sales_ly
into #temp2
from #temp1 ty left join #temp1 ly
on ty.product_code = ly.product_code
and ty.store_code = ly.store_code 
and trunc(dateadd(year, -1, ty.business_date)) = ly.business_date;

-- check
select to_char(business_date, 'yyyymm'), sum(sales) ty, sum(sale_ly) as ly
from #temp2
group by to_char(business_date,'yyyymm')
order by 1;
```

Comment: would you like to try and create two temporary tables one for current year and another for previous year in separate queries and compare the structure

Answer (score 0):

You have join - `trunc(dateadd(year, -1, ty.business_date)) = ly.business_date;`

You are trying to compare sales of particular day of this year with last year `(22/02/2019 with 22/02/2018)`

In your table, do you have data for both of these days, aggregated sample data from your table could help in writing the query.

Query -

```
with  sales_tab as (
select '2019/02/22' as date1, 123 as store, 456 as prod, 20 sales from dual
union
select '2019/02/23' as date1, 123 as store, 456 as prod, 30 as sales from dual
union
select '2019/02/24' as date1, 123 as store, 456 as prod, 40 sales from dual
union
select '2018/02/22' as date1, 123 as store, 456 as prod, 60 sales from dual
union
select '2018/02/23' as date1, 123 as store, 456 as prod, 70 as sales from dual
union
select '2018/02/25' as date1, 123 as store, 456 as prod, 80 sales from dual)
select 
t1.date1, t2.date1, t1.store, t1.prod, t1.sales this_year, t2.sales prev_year
from sales_tab t1 left outer join sales_tab t2 on 
(t1.store=t2.store 
and t1.prod=t2.prod
and cast(substr(t1.date1,1,4) as int)-1=cast(substr(t2.date1, 1,4) as int)
and substr(t1.date1,6,2)=substr(t2.date1,6,2)
and substr(t1.date1,9,2)=substr(t2.date1,9,2)
);
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve, comparing up to the actual day, year on year (i.e. 22/02/2019 vs 22/02/2018). I am unable to share aggregated data, due to company's policy, but there are only 5 columns, (date, store code, product code, sales this year, sales last year). The problem must lies behind the join of store code and product code, because when I remove them and just have date alone, the numbers come back correct.

Comment: Your query should work, updated my question with sample data. i am getting right results

Comment: It works in the ideal scenario where the store and product sold exist in both periods. My data contains the possibility that there are new stores opening/ old ones closing, selling/removing products from its range. That's when the mismatch of sales happen.